# logica de programação JQUERY

Tags: jquery, lógica

Fala pessoal! não estou conseguindo raciocinar em um probleminha que estou querendo melhorar o codigo.
tenho varias divs(Content1,Content2,Content3....), possuo uma function que verifica qual Content esta ativo na tela(n).
Verificando qual n ta ativo, faço outra div aparecer.
até aí tudo bem, porém se eu tiver 50 contents, eu tenho que fazer 50 comandos de seleção para verificar qual content esta ativo.
O que vocês me recomendam pra não usar tantos comandos de seleção?
MUITO OBRIGADO.

HTML:

```
<div class="content-switcher" id="Content1">
<div class="imagemblock" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>
<div class="content-switcher" id="Content2">
<div class="imagemblock" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>
<div class="content-switcher" id="Content3">
<div class="imagemblock" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
 function selectStep(n) { 
//A MAGIA ESTA AQUI. NÃO GOSTARIA DE FAZER TANTOS "IFS".
if(n==1){
     $('#Content1 .imagemblock').fadeIn().show();
}
if(n==2){
     $('#Content2 .imagemblock').fadeIn().show();
}
if(n==3){
     $('#Content3 .imagemblock').fadeIn().show();
}
//OS CONTENTS SÃO MUDADOS COM OUTRO TREXO DE CODIGO DE ONCLICK.
 $(".content-switcher").hide();
    $("#Content" + n).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode colocar dentro de um loop, pesquisando quantos elementos começam com o `id` *Content*:

```
function selectStep(n) {
    // obtem a qtd de elementos na tela que começa com Content
    var size = $("div[id^='Content']").length;
    for (var i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
        if (n == i) {
            $('#Content' + n + ' .imagemblock').fadeIn().show();
        }
    }
    //OS CONTENTS SÃO MUDADOS COM OUTRO TREXO DE CODIGO DE ONCLICK.
    $(".content-switcher").hide();
    $("#Content" + n).show();
}
```

Comment: Que maravilha! resolveu meus problemas! Obrigado Lucas! :)